# Connect by clause confusion

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a problem, I need to get the o/p like A emp working  under manager B emp and B emp  is under manger of C, then the A employee must be connected to C. I worked out using hierarchy query , but not able find 0/p .

Example:

```
Select * from emp where mgr=7566 --(consider these as c);
"EMPNO" "ENAME"     "JOB"     "MGR"   "HIREDATE"    "SAL"   "COMM"  "DEPTNO"
7788     "SCOTT"     "ANALYST"     7566   19-APR-87     3000            20 
7902     "FORD"      "ANALYST"     7566    03-DEC-81    3000            20

--- now JONES is mgr of  "SCOTT"  and I have taken 7788 (scott)

select * from emp where mgr=7788;
"EMPNO" "ENAME" "JOB"   "MGR"   "HIREDATE"  "SAL"   "COMM"  "DEPTNO"
7876    "ADAMS" "CLERK" 7788    23-MAY-87   1100        20
```

Now we can see that Scott is mgr of Adams.. I need to get relation between Adams and jones .. i worked on the below sql, but not able get the 0/p..

```
select * from emp connect by prior empno=mgr  start with mgr 
in ( select mgr from emp where mgr=7566)
and empno=7876.
```

Experts please provide some I/p on this ..

Comment: Can you provide a sample on sqlfiddle.com ?

Comment: What are you looking for? explain that. You want a table that shows the realtionship between 'A' and 'C' employees? a table which tells us that 'C' is the manager of 'A'?

Comment: @pokies Hi.. yes exactly  I need O/P which tells C is indirectly manager of A or Related to A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want 3-level relationships between employees and managers. Try this query:

```
SELECT e1.empno, e2.mgr
FROM emp AS e1 INNER JOIN emp AS e2
WHERE e1.mgr = e2.empno
```

Pay attention that this sql query would not return the top manager of each employee.

So if 'B' is manager of 'A' and also 'C' is manager of 'B', the query would return 'A' and 'C'.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like the following, showing the "top manager" of every employee:

```
with emp(empno, name, mgr) as
(
select 7788, 'SCOTT', 7566 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 7902, 'FORD',  7566 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 7566, 'JONES', 9999 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 7876, 'ADAMS', 7788 FROM DUAL
)
select name, mgr
from
(
    select name AS MGR, connect_by_root(name) as name, level as lev, connect_by_isleaf leaf
    from emp
    connect by prior MGR =  EMPNO
)
where leaf = 1 and lev > 1
```